# Send Email with pentaho PDI

Tags: email, pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I want to sent an email using PDI. I created an job and added the 'Mail' element. There are my parameters.

```
Server smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Use Authentication
User : mygmailusername
Pass : mygmailpass
Secure Con Type : TLS
```

When I run the job I get the error :`Problem while sending message : javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`

When I changed the port to 465 gmail rejected the message and sent an email to mygmailusername indicating unauthorised login attempt.

However I have changed the port for my BI server to 9090. I dont know if this is also a reason. Am assuming PDI is to communicate somehow with BI server if it is the BI server which is to send the email. How do I get this to work please ?

Comment: Have you tried with SSL instead of TLS? And the fact that GMail sent you an e-mail shows that the correct port is 465, IMHO. To send an e-mail, the sending port is not relevant, only the receiving port matters, again IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was finally able to get this to work. I changed my config to :

```
Server smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
Use Authentication
User : mygmailusername
Pass : mygmailpass
Secure Con Type : SSL
```

Then I run the PDI job and this caused google to send a `Suspicious sign-in prevented` email to `mygmailusername` account. I opened the email and clicked on the http://support.google.com/mail?p=client_login. at the bottom of the email. This took me to a troubleshooting page.

Under the section **Now, please follow the steps below to resolve the problem:** I clicked on the link at the third option http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and then clicked continue. Now it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should try with:

```
Port 465 or 587
Secure Con Type SSL
```

If it doesn't work, check your GMail account for the SMTP configuration, but I think these are standard.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the mail step with @flexxxit answer and the following adicional setup on Gmail account to decrease its security when sending e-mails by apps:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Avoid this configuration because "your account is no longer protected by modern security standards" when turn on the "Access for less secure apps".

I made this test only to check if the Pentaho DI Job is working.