# Pentaho 5.0.1 CE bi-server gmail configuration

Tags: email, gmail, sendmail, pentaho, mail-server

I refer to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302855/send-email-with-pentaho-pdi?noredirect=1#comment28624601_19302855) and how I solved it. I am now using the latest version of pentaho and I cant seem to get the email configuration working.

```
Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
Use Authentication: Yes
User : mygmailusername
Pass : mygmailpass
protocol: smtp (instead of smtps)
Secure Con Type : SSL
```

When I enter the details in the admin settings and click `test email configuration` it fails. The thing is that as I mentioned in my earlier question this config works fine in pdi and am able to send emails. However it is does not seem to work for bi-server. Are there some files I need to modify or what? Also I have tried all other possible configs (protocol:smtps, port:587) etc. and still failure. Why does this config work in pdi and not biserver ?

Comment: @hadinbe Can you help me out here pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally had to change the configuration to

```
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Authentication: Yes (checked)
User Name: mygmailusername@gmail.com
Pass : mygmailpass
Protocol: smtp (or smtps; both work for me)
Address all email from server will come from: mygmailusername@gmail.com
Use Start TLS: Yes (checked)
Use SSL: Yes (checked)
```

Now Pentaho 5.0.1 BiServer Can send emails via gmail smtp. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in Pentaho Server 7 CE; so make sure to use below configuration -

```
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Authentication: Yes (checked)
User Name: mygmailusername@gmail.com
Pass : mygmailpass
Protocol: smtp (or smtps; both work for me)
Address all email from server will come from: mygmailusername@gmail.com
Use Start TLS: Yes (checked)
Use SSL: Yes (checked)
Email "From" Address: mygmailusername@gmail.com
```